# My red leaf corkscrew hazel is going green?

Tags: trees, leaves

I have a [red corkscrew hazel](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/97648/i-Corylus-avellana-i-Contorta/Details):

[image: corylus-avellana-red-majestic]

It's in a large pot, and I'm not in a position to plant it out (nor will I be any time soon).

However I've noticed that some of the leaves are going green - a lot like the one in the photo (this isn't mine, but it's doing the same thing).

Is this a cause for concern? And if it is, what is the appropriate way to address this?

Answer (score 2):

This is totally normal for purple-leaved varieties!  Extremely health, happy looking plant!  Don't have to do anything...except, I couldn't see the pot, have no idea of size.  Are you going to keep it in a pot?  Make sure you use great POTTING soil out of a bag!  Do not use garden soil!  Do not use any gravel or rocks as 'drainage' beneath the soil.  Just use sterilized potting soil preferably with mychorhyzae (sp) and bacteria included.  Use an extended release fertilizer 2 -3 times per year such as Osmocote. Make sure your pot drains very well.  Set it up off the porch, patio or ground to facilitate drainage. Use tiles, rocks or 'pot feet' to make sure there is an air layer beneath the bottom of the pot and surface it sits upon.

Prune back branches from the middle that are small and/or orient towards the center of the plant. Leave no stubs. The beauty of this plant is during the winter!!  This purple variety extends the beauty and value of this plant as a specimen.  The catkins that are so prized on this guy are part of the reproductive system and this means the plant should not be fertilized late in the year with fertilizer that has too much nitrogen.  Make sure your fertilizer is 14-14-14 or 6-6-6 where the first number indicating nitrogen is the same percentage OR LOWER. If the first number is higher than the last 2 numbers, don't use it.  Osmocote satisfies this recommendation.

Place this plant where it can be appreciated!! Oh, if your climate has below freezing weather, you can wrap the pot and plant in burlap bags or even newspaper.  String Xmas lights inside before you cover it to keep the temperature above freezing.  Potted plants are easily killed by cold temperatures as a plant's main weakness are its roots.  Roots in a pot are easily killed.  I wouldn't use clay for a pot if your winters are sub zero.  They'll retain water and the frozen water will break your pot to smithereens...

Or put it in a heated greenhouse, garage and keep soil slightly moist...beautiful plant!!

Answer (score 1):

In shadier conditions, the leaves will be more green than red - often, larger leaves may shade smaller ones on the same plant, and those will be less red, but unless your plant has produced a stem with all green leaves and no red ones, in which case it should be pruned out at the point from which it originates, there's no need to worry. Some variation in colour is quite normal, and the newest leaves are always the most colourful.